# why does child divs take 100% height of parent div with display: grid

Tags: html, css

I have a paren div which is has display grid and height 100%. for some reason all the children divs inside it now have height 100% even though i didnt specify the height to have 100%. How can i make the child divs have the height based on their content.

```css
.parent {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  gap: 0;
}

.child {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="child-1">
      child
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: default stretch alignment

Comment: @TemaniAfif how do i change that

Comment: by chaging align-items on the parent or align-self on child

Comment: The question has been helpfully edited to show the code in a runnable form, but the runnable code sample doesn't seem to actually demonstrate the problem in the text of the question.

Comment: @TemaniAfif i tried align-items: normal on the parent div and the children divs are still 100% height

Comment: @user3775998 Read my detailed answer which shows this is the default intended behaviour.

Comment: normal is the same as stretch, try something else

Comment: @TemaniAfif i also tried other properties still the same thing

Comment: show us what are you trying, we see nothing

Comment: Sidenote: You don't need to set  `width: 100%;` for `.child` either. It's the default grid cell behaviour for block level elements like `div` and is controlled by `justify-items` on the parent or `justify-self` on the cells.

Comment: @connexo yes. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Cause

The reason is that the default value for the CSS property `align-items` on a grid-container is `normal`. This property defines the `align-self` behaviour (vertical alignment) of those grid cells which don't explicitly set `align-self`.

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items):

`normal`

> The effect of this keyword is dependent of the layout mode we are in:
>
> - In absolutely-positioned layouts, the keyword behaves like start on replaced absolutely-positioned boxes, and as stretch on all other absolutely-positioned boxes.
> - In static position of absolutely-positioned layouts, the keyword behaves as stretch.
> - For flex items, the keyword behaves as stretch.
> - **For grid items, this keyword leads to a behavior similar to the one of `stretch`, except for boxes with an aspect ratio or an intrinsic sizes where it behaves like `start`.**
> - The property doesn't apply to block-level boxes, and to table cells.

```css
html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; color: white; }

.parent {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  gap: 10px;
}

.child {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    child 1
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    child 2
  </div>
</div>
```

### Solution

If you want **all** your grid-cells to start at the top of the cell and have `height: auto`, simply apply `align-items: start;` on your grid container:

```css
html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; color: white; }

.parent {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  gap: 10px;
  align-items: start;
}

.child {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    child 1
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    child 2
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want **only some** of your grid-cells to start at the top of the cell and have `height: auto`, simply apply `align-self: start;` on those grid cells:

```css
html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; color: white; }

.parent {
  background-color: orange;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  gap: 10px;
}

.child {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
}

.auto-height {
  align-self: start;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child auto-height">
    child 1
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    child 2
  </div>
</div>
```